# HTML/CSS - Trouble getting text to overlay image

Tags: html, css, image, text

The title explains a-lot of the issue. I am an unable to get the text to overlay the image. I wish to have the text in the centre of image inside the div I've put it in.

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

#main-page-content {
max-width:960px;
margin:auto;
max-height: 500px;
position: relative; 
}

#bitcoin-price-space {
  width: 960px;
  padding-top:20px;
  height: 40px; 
  margin:auto;
}

.bitcoin-price-content {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
right:  100;
width: 100%; 
}
```

HTML (Sorry about how this is formatted):

```
<div id="bitcoin-price-space"> 
      </div>
      <div id="main-page-content">
       <table align="center" width="960px" border="0">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <div class="bitcoin-price-content">                                                                                                                     <td align="center">
<img src="data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png"                                                            width="80%" height="275" align="center"    onMouseOver="this.src='data/design/images/buy-bitcoins-hover.png'"
onMouseOut="this.src='data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png'"alt=""/></td>
<h2 align="right">Test</h2>
   </div>
                      <td background=align="center"><img src="data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png" width="80%" height="275" align="center" onMouseOver="this.src='data/design/images/sell-bitcoins-hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png'" alt="" id="bitcoin-sell-image"/></td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

Result of the above code:
[image: Result]

Comment: Your html looks messed up. go use this http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: what! `div` inside `tr`?

Comment: Your code result look like this currently: http://jsfiddle.net/dvsm71t3/. What is your expected result?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your expected output??

Comment: Could you make the images background images, and put the text into the table cell directly? (Instead of having an `<h2>` outside the table cell which you have to try to position back into the cell)

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a table here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tables, only 1 image the rest is CSS version. The hover effect is also handled by CSS. It isn't exactly what you started with but should give you something to think about.

```css
.bitcoin-transaction
{
  width:900px;
  padding:0 30px;
  
}

.bitcoin-transaction>div
{
  height:310px; /*Height + Margin*/
  width:384px; /*0.8 * 960 / 2 */
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:35px;
  border:solid 2px #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 13px -7px rgba(34,34,34,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 13px -7px rgba(34,34,34,1);
box-shadow: 10px 10px 13px -7px rgba(34,34,34,1);
  position:relative;
  padding-top:32px;
  
}

.bitcoin-transaction>div:hover
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px -5px rgba(34,34,34,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px -5px rgba(34,34,34,1);
box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px -5px rgba(34,34,34,1);
}

.bitcoin-transaction .sell
{
  float:left;
  background-color:#F00;
}

.bitcoin-transaction .sell:hover
{
  background-color:#F33;
  
}

.bitcoin-transaction .buy
{
  float:right;
  background-color:#0F0;
}


.bitcoin-transaction .buy:hover
{
  background-color:#3F3;
}


.bitcoin-transaction>div:hover:before
{
  transform:rotate(15deg);
}

.bitcoin-transaction>div:before /*bitcoin logo*/
{
  transform:rotate(30deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  position:absolute;
  top:-32px;
  left:160px;
  height:64px;
  width:64px;
  content: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<div id="main-page-content">
  <div class="bitcoin-transaction">
    <div class="sell">
      <h2>Sell Bitcoins</h2>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="buy">
      <h2>Buy Bitcoins</h2>
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. No tables is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your H2 in an absolute positioned div, don't try to make your H2 absolute.  You'll need to tweak the padding based off the actual size of your image.

CSS

```
#main-page-content {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    position: relative; 
}

#bitcoin-price-space {
    width: 960px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height: 40px; 
    margin:auto;
}

.bitcoin-price-content {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.bitcoin-text { 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 80px 60px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bitcoin-price-space"></div>
<div id="main-page-content">
    <table align="center" width="960px" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><div class="bitcoin-text"><h2 align="right">Test</h2></div>
    <img src="data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png" width="80%" height="275" align="center" onMouseOver="this.src='data/design/images/buy-bitcoins-hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png'" alt=""/></td>
    <td background=align="center"><img src="data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png" width="80%" height="275" align="center" onMouseOver="this.src='data/design/images/sell-bitcoins-hover.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png'" alt="" id="bitcoin-sell-image"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Although your better alternative is to use the background image of the td...

CSS

```
#main-page-content {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    position: relative; 
}

#bitcoin-price-space {
    width: 960px;
    padding-top:20px;
    height: 40px; 
    margin:auto;
}

.bitcoin-price-content {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bitcoin-price-space"></div>
<div id="main-page-content">
    <table align="center" width="960px" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="background-image:url('data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png')" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url(data/design/images/buy-bitcoins-hover.png)';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url(data/design/images/buy-bitcoins.png)';">Test</td>
    <td align="center" style="background-image:url('data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png')" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url(data/design/images/sell-bitcoins-hover.png)';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundImage='url(data/design/images/sell-bitcoins.png)';">Test</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your h2 inside the `<td>` element then set `position:relative` to your `<td>` element.

Maybe you wanted something like this :

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

#main-page-content {
max-width:960px;
margin:auto;
max-height: 500px;
position: relative; 
}

#bitcoin-price-space {
  width: 960px;
  padding-top:20px;
  height: 40px; 
  margin:auto;
}

.bitcoin-price-content {
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
width: 100%; 
  color:#fff;
  z-index: 2;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  position:relative;
 } 

 td img {
   margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="bitcoin-price-space"> 
      </div>
      <div id="main-page-content">
       <table align="center" width="960px" border="0">
       <tbody>
       <tr>
       <div class="bitcoin-price-content">                                                                        <td align="center">
                 <h2 align="right">Test</h2>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"                                                            width="80%" height="275" align="center"   alt=""/>
 
         </td>

                      <td background=align="center">
                        <h2 align="right">Another Test</h2>
                        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" width="80%" height="275" align="center"  alt="" id="bitcoin-sell-image"/>
         
         </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>


   </div>
```